# PATH variable shows one thing, pwd shows something slightly different? Causing problems calling script

Tags: bash

I'm currently attempting to write a bash script, and I've come across a problem when trying to run it. I've added the directory in which I saved the script and it shows up as
`/Users/azrosen92/Documents/WebDev/bash_hack/` in the `$PATH` variable, but when I use `pwd` while I am in the directory, it shows up as `/Users/azrosen92/Documents/WebDev/bash_hack`. Is that last slash at the end of the `$PATH` variable the reason why my script wont run?

EDIT: okay so I ran it using the entire path and it worked so it must be something with the `$PATH` variable

Comment: it shouldn't be; you almost certainly have a different problem. perhaps the error messages, if any, might help ascertain the problem?

Comment: The trailing slash designates that `bash_hack` is definitely a directory and it is a good practice to use it. Have you sourced your profile file (`.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`) after you updated the `$PATH`?

Comment: The error I'm getting is `-bash: bash_hack: command not found` and I did source my .bashrc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the script file has name `.../WebDev/bash_hack`, and you wish to run it by `bash_hack`, it is inappropriate to add the name of the file itself to `$PATH`. Rather, `$PATH` should contain the directory in which the executable is contained.

In this case, `$PATH` should not include `/Users/azrosen92/Documents/WebDev/bash_hack/`, but `/Users/azrosen92/Documents/WebDev/` (and the trailing slash is optional).

Comment: The script file is located in the `.../WebDev/bash_hack/` directory

Comment: while in the directory, can you run it by `./bash_hack`?

Answer (score 0):

Your script should be an executable, for the system to execute it from any directory even if your script path is added in `PATH` environment variable. To give execute permissions do the following

`chmod u+x your_script`

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I was only typing in `bash_hack` without the `.sh` so when I typed `bash_hack.sh` it worked

Comment: the lesson here, perhaps, is that the file name is the *whole* file name?